# slow javascript depending on screen

Tags: javascript, performance, screen, retina-display, frame-rate

i'm having a "framerate" problem with a script on a website i'm building:

When the browser window is on the external screen (an apple led display), the animations works perfectly fine, but when i pull the same window on my laptop screen, the animations are awfully slow (about 1 fps).

My conputer is a brand new macBookPro, with a 13 inch retina display and a very good configuration, the screen settings are set (for both screens) on "optimised for the screen".

The mouse cursor, scroll or any other animation on the (default/retina) screen seems to work normally, so i would say it is not a refresh problem of the whole screen.

I cant figure out why this happens, or think of a method to find out, so i would be grateful for any kind of advice (or solution).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: **show us code** What are your displays resolution? I guess you're doing a for loop on each pixel of the screen or similar, so the bigger the resolution is, the harder it is for your computer…

Comment: i'm sorry but i am not allowed to show any code, but basically what it does is: when the mouse is moved, the background position of a div is eased to the position (using something like:pos += (pos-mousex)/10) when the pos is close enough, the animation is stopped (event is removed). My resolution is 2560 by 1600 on the big screen and 2560 by 1600 on the retina one.
By the way: i tried to have at the same time a window on the big screen and on the small one, and it worked on the big one but not on the small one

Comment: This start to be interesting. My first guess was wrong as you've got the same resolution on both screens. Unfortunately without code, I won't be able to help you much. Maybe this question should be asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com/…